# Comparing Data Before and After Form Submission

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, serialization

I have a form page in which many of the elements are saved to different tables and different rows in my db. In order to minimize db calls I would like to compare the data before and after form submission, then I can write a function which will only update data that has been changed. To accomplish this I am saving the array that I used to build the form in a session file:

```
$this->session->set_tempdata('form_values_'.$item['id'],json_encode($item), 86400);
```

On form submission I retrieve this data and compare it to the $_POST:

```
$pre_post = json_decode($_SESSION['form_values_'.$_POST['id']], true);
```

Everything works great except in a few textareas where there is a "." in my test data. For some reason these fields come back as not equal even though I'm not changing the data.

It is definitely the period that is causing the problem, when I remove it it works fine. On the other hand there are other textareas that have periods that are not causing problems.

I thought it might be codeigniter's XSS filtering, but I removed that and it made no difference.

Originally i was using serialize to encode the array for storage, but I switched to json_encode and again it made no difference.

Here is the code I am using to compare the values:

```
$pre_post = json_decode($_SESSION['form_values_'.$_POST['id']], true);
$post = $this->security->xss_clean($_POST);
foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
    if( !isset($pre_post[$key]) || trim($value)!=trim($pre_post[$key]) ){
        $post_post[$key] = $value; 
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you comparing the data to ? what's the difference between your pre_post save in session and $post?

Comment: Sorry I thought that was clear in my question. The pre_post is the array I used to build the form with the original data from the db. I am comparing that to the $_POST, ie what was returned by the form. Right now I'm just testing and it and not changing anything, so everything should come back as equal. However as I said some of the text fields are coming back as not equal.

Comment: ok, if you don't mind. Can you post data from the db and data post form submission? it will help figuring out the problem.

Comment: `[note/154] => 650. 75, 38 `

Comment: sorry didn't mean to add that comment yet, but that is an example of one of the fields that is giving me problems. That is copied from the array before form submission, below is copied from the $_POST,
[note/154] => 650. 75, 38

Comment: Thinking about it I realize that the problem might lay in where the data came from. This particular db began life in a Microsoft Access program. Later it was moved to a MySQL db on our server, and modified by a webpage form with a simple textarea. Later the webpage was updated so that the textareas had tinymce, ie the data was submitted as html instead of simply text. This particular piece of data could have been saved at any stage.
In other words it could have been sent from Access, as plain text, or as html code

Comment: I just compared the 2 strings and it returned true,                                      `$str1 = '650. 75, 38';  
            $str2 = '650. 75, 38';  
            echo ($str1 == $str2 ) ? 'true' : 'false'; //true  
            echo ($str1 === $str2 ) ? 'true' : 'false'; //true`

Comment: That is exactly the problem, they clearly should be equal but they aren't. Which means there is something in either the way the data is stored or the way it is encoded which is creating a difference between the values

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may be it help you

```html
$select = "SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." WHERE ".$field_name ." = '".$value."'";
        $result_latest = mysql_query($select) or trigger_error(mysql_error()); 
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_latest,MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
                $data_new = array_intersect_key($row,$data);
       foreach($data_new as $k=>$v)
                {
                    if(strcmp($row[$k],$data[$k]) != 0)
                    {
         $string .= '`'.$k.'` = "'.$data[$k].'" ,';
                    }
                }
            }
     $string = rtrim($string, ",");
        if($string != NULL){
        $update_sql = "UPDATE ".$table_name." SET ".$string." WHERE ".$field_name." = "."'".$value."'";
           $query = $CI->db->query($update_sql);
        }
```

Comment: In the above code it will compare new and old data of form and what ever fields data are changed it will update only that.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but the issue isn't how to write the function. The problem is why the following two strings are not considered equal:
"650. 75, 38",
"650. 75, 38"
one is pulled from the database and store in a serialized file, the other is returned from the form

Comment: Try `if(strcmp($data1,$data2) != 0)` it will compare strings and before comparing use trim. i have test it works.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work, I got the same results with `if( strcmp(trim($pre_post_value),trim($post_value)) == 0 )` as I got with `if( trim($pre_post_value) == trim($post_value) )` by the way strcmp doesn't trim the value for you